# Вопросы по тестированию Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Есть старый проект, нужно покрыть его тестами. База и сущности рассинхронны. Миграция сделана из дампа базы с помощью доктрины. Возникли сложности с интеграционными тестами, а именно с рефрешем тестовой базой и миграциями.

**1) Как рефрешить тестовую БД?.** Хотелось бы рефрешить базу перед каждым тестом. Как сделать это адекватно? Нашел такое решение, оно рабочее, но выглядит "так себе": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752930/best-way-to-create-a-test-database-and-load-fixtures-on-symfony-2-webtestcase

После Ларавел, где для рефреша достаточно трейт прописать, выглядит немного адово. Неужели нет ничего из коробки для такой тривиальной задачи?

**2) Как подключить в тесты sqlite?** С помощью ссылки из п.1 смог дропать и заного создавать базу, потом миграции, но на mysql это выходит дико долго. Чисто выполнение миграции схемы базы - секунд 5. И так на каждый тест.  Думал перевести тесты на sqlite in memory. Но возникла проблема, прямо в миграциях присутствует такой код:

```
$this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');
```

Что не дает выполнить миграции на sqlite. Естественно, я попробовал его убрать - но тогда ошибки синтаксиса.

Ради интесера сделал миграцию через `doctrine:migrations:diff`  - но и там присутстсвует такой код. Погуглил, и вроде как DBAL что-то там не коннектит с sqlite. И тут у меня когнитивный диссонанс - в доке по тестам симфони прописан sqlite, а DBAL не может с ней что-то и как-то работать.

Собственно вопрос: как вывести тесты и миграции на sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание [вот сюда](https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle/blob/master/src/DAMA/DoctrineTestBundle/PHPUnit/PHPUnitExtension.php)

Насколько я помню суть там в  том, что есть хуки, которые дергаются в момент изменений БД, а суть хуков в том что все  изменения заворачиваются в транзацкии и после выполнения выполняется RollBack
А вот собственно сам [бандл](https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle). 
Выглядит это по крайней мере достаточно неплохо на первый взгляд. Я не пользовал сам но кто то  говорил мне что они применяют это на практике достаточно успешно.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. Вроде еще есть Лип бандл. Но все это отдельные бандлы даже не от команды симфони. 
Пока решил через команду, каждый раз создавать схему от сущностей. Вроже ок рабтает для sqlite in memory. Еще был вариант через пуджер (что предлагается в симфони каст), но он работает с внешними ключами кривовато,  даже там это пишется.